# How to convert NSURLConnecion statement to Xcode 7 (swift 2.0)?

Tags: ios, swift2

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
                (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
```

Sorry, new to iOS, etc. Just cannot convert it. Xcode beta 7.0 (7A121I)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your included code, it looks like the syntax for your closure (completion handler) is incorrect. I'm not 100% sure if this will work as I don't have Xcode in front of me but try something like this:

```
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: { (response, data, error) -> Void in
        // code here
    })
```

Comment: seems to accept the syntax, but generates a new error as I am trying to load images asynchronously.

Comment: sorry error is in line:   let picture = UIImage(data: data)     says that "data" is undefined. ????

Comment: oops, sorry dum response.  did not do as you said to move code to point indicated.  syntax works for now.  will try execution later after i have fixed all Xcode upgrade errors. thank you

Comment: @MicheleDiblasi No problem. Just a quick side note. Take a look at using NSURLSession instead of NSURLConnection as it's more recent. And/or, consider taking a look at AlamoFire if you haven't already. It's by Mattt Thompson and is AFNetworking but for Swift.